# I have 3 tables with dates to which I want to join to a date dimension table but it is returning many duplicates with left joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dimensions

I have 4 tables with dates to which I want to join to a date dimension table but it is returning many duplicates with left joins.

Tables are basically a date field which I want to count.

```
     mdate datetime, mordate varchar(10),fteam varchar(20)
     sdate datetime,fteam varchar(20)
     bdate datetime,fteam varchar(20)
```

These are actually one table with the separate dates which I am joining 3 times to the dimension table to get one dataset. Also this table

```
    compdate datetime, fteam varchar(20)
```

and the date dimension table  as date in yyyymmdd,which I join on the date field.
as

```
    select cp.fteam,md.mdate,sd.sdate,bd.bdate,cp.cpdate,d.date

     into #resultstable

    from datedimension d 
    left join mdate md
    on d.date = convert(date,md.mdate,103)
    left join sentdate sd
    on d.date = convert(date,sd.sdate,103)
    left join bacdate bd
    on d.date = convert(date,bd.bdate,103)
    left join compdate cp
    on d.date = convert(date,cp.cdate,103)
```

Doing this I want the dates in the date dimension to give me one date I can use a where clause on to get counts of each date from the 4 different tables for a report.

However it is giving me many repeats as each time a there is a matching date you get the same line repeated repeated for the matching date on all tables.
This gives many counts which are wrong.
ie
if md table has a record 2 records for 2016/06/29 and cp has 3 and bd has six
The dimension date result will be 36! for md when it should only be showing 2!, ie 6x3x2.

How can I join these tables with causing repeats and incorrect results.

I thought it would be a standard way to join fact tables with a dimension table to give accurate results and not duplicates as you are join sets together.

I have tried picking only the dates from each table only but it still gives repeats.
I cannot show a schema as company details but you can put together a hypothetical one from the tables shown.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why are you storing dates as strings in your dimension table?

Comment: dates are dates, not strings, the convert is to remove the time part.

Comment: I think your multiple fact tables are colliding.  If you can imagine having the mocdate table with only 2 rows in it, both of which have a date of 1/1/2016.  If you only join datedimension to mocdate, you'll get back 2 rows of data.  Now imagine sentdate has only 1 row of data, also for 1/1/2016.  If you now join sentdate to the virtual table created above, you will end up with 2 rows from sentdate because there are already 2 rows as a result of mocdate.

Comment: Yes that's right I am aware of that, how can I overcome this. Thanks for understanding the issue.

Comment: A Microsoft MVP has suggested 2 methods to deal with this but his response is too long to post here, basically he said 1. Do the aggregates before and then join. and 2. add a row number to each column using row_number over partition by the column and order for each column and then join them on the row numbers, the ordering is our choice. I think if I get one row for the selected column in question it will stop returning false duplicate rows that don't belong to the data of that column. Say if I am querying the mocdate column this should stop matches from other columns results. Will try for now

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is that because none of your fact tables relate to each other, you are essentially creating a Cartesian product for the fact tables--where they only relate to each other by date.

Consider this simplified version of your example, where I also include some sample data for "today":

```
CREATE TABLE #fact1 (id int identity, dt datetime, val varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE #fact2 (id int identity, dt datetime, val varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE #fact3 (id int identity, dt datetime, val varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE #fact4 (id int identity, dt datetime, val varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE #date (dt datetime, val varchar(5));
GO

INSERT INTO #fact1 (dt, val) VALUES (GETDATE(),'fact1');
INSERT INTO #fact2 (dt, val) VALUES (GETDATE(),'fact2');
INSERT INTO #fact3 (dt, val) VALUES (GETDATE(),'fact3');
INSERT INTO #fact4 (dt, val) VALUES (GETDATE(),'fact4');
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
GO 5

INSERT INTO #date (dt, val) VALUES (CAST(GETDATE() AS date),'Today');
GO


SELECT *
FROM #date d
JOIN #fact1 AS f1 ON d.dt = CAST(f1.dt AS date)
JOIN #fact2 AS f2 ON d.dt = CAST(f2.dt AS date)
JOIN #fact3 AS f3 ON d.dt = CAST(f3.dt AS date)
JOIN #fact4 AS f4 ON d.dt = CAST(f4.dt AS date);
GO

DROP TABLE #fact1;
DROP TABLE #fact2;
DROP TABLE #fact3;
DROP TABLE #fact4;
DROP TABLE #date;
GO
```

Note that 625 rows are returned. This is the Cartesian product of the four fact tables, which is then joined to the dimension table. This happens because there is no relation between the fact tables other than the date. As a result, any **one** row for "today" in one fact table is joined to **every** row for "today" in **every other** fact table.

Instead, consider how your four fact tables related WITHOUT the join to the date dimension table. Re-write your query so that the data makes sense before joining to the date dimension. Do the tables relate on something like an order_id or any other aspect?

If the fact tables only relate insomuch as you are aggregating them by date--then yes, you'll need to take another approach:

a) Aggregate by date first, then join the aggregated sets together. This option makes the most sense if you only need the aggregated values, and don't need the full details for your report.

```
SELECT *
FROM #date d
JOIN (SELECT CAST(dt AS date) AS dt, count(*) AS dt_count 
      FROM #fact1 GROUP BY CAST(dt AS date)) AS f1 ON d.dt = f1.dt
JOIN (SELECT CAST(dt AS date) AS dt, count(*) AS dt_count 
      FROM #fact2 GROUP BY CAST(dt AS date)) AS f2 ON d.dt = f2.dt
JOIN (SELECT CAST(dt AS date) AS dt, count(*) AS dt_count 
      FROM #fact3 GROUP BY CAST(dt AS date)) AS f3 ON d.dt = f3.dt
JOIN (SELECT CAST(dt AS date) AS dt, count(*) AS dt_count 
      FROM #fact4 GROUP BY CAST(dt AS date)) AS f4 ON d.dt = f4.dt
```

b) Assign an arbitrary row_number() for each calendar day, then use that as a secondary join criterion. If the data doesn't actually relate, this option might work, but the detailed result set is largely meaningless when all data in a single row doesn't refer to a single entity. This might give you the right numbers, but is logically a useless result set.

```
SELECT *
FROM #date d
JOIN (SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(dt AS date) ORDER BY dt) AS row_num
      FROM #fact1 ) AS f1 ON d.dt = CAST(f1.dt AS date) 
JOIN (SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(dt AS date) ORDER BY dt) AS row_num
      FROM #fact2 ) AS f2 ON d.dt = CAST(f2.dt AS date) AND f1.row_num = f2.row_num
JOIN (SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(dt AS date) ORDER BY dt) AS row_num
      FROM #fact3 ) AS f3 ON d.dt = CAST(f3.dt AS date) AND f1.row_num = f3.row_num
JOIN (SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(dt AS date) ORDER BY dt) AS row_num
      FROM #fact4 ) AS f4 ON d.dt = CAST(f4.dt AS date) AND f1.row_num = f4.row_num
```

c) Break this up into separate statements: one for each fact table. Optionally `UNION` those results into a single result set. This result set could then be further aggregated/grouped to give you the results you want.

```
SELECT *, 'Fact 1' AS SourceTable
FROM #date d
JOIN #fact1 AS f1 ON d.dt = CAST(f1.dt AS date)
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'Fact 2' AS SourceTable
FROM #date d
JOIN #fact2 AS f2 ON d.dt = CAST(f2.dt AS date)
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'Fact 3' AS SourceTable
FROM #date d
JOIN #fact3 AS f3 ON d.dt = CAST(f3.dt AS date)
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'Fact 4' AS SourceTable
FROM #date d
JOIN #fact4 AS f4 ON d.dt = CAST(f4.dt AS date);
```

In my opinion, options a & c offer the best solutions when the fact tables don't otherwise relate to each other. Option b might work, but you would need to be very careful that your data is meaningful & doesn't create confusing or erroneous results.

Additionally, while it is orthogonal to the question asked, keep in mind that applying a function to a join criteria (in this case, `CONVERT`ing the date column) will prevent index usage, resulting in a table scan.

Comment: I've looked at option a) already but it is given still false rows for a test of two date tables. ie mocdate and sentdate. There is a Fteam column which is the only relation between the two tables. So for your example you could add a fteam column in each fact table and see if it works. I am going to try out the row_number solution otherwise I am thinking of using a function to return the number of reviews for a particular date and joining this to the other 3 tables(remember these tables are essentially 1 table), Thanks for your help it gives me an outline to try.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single date table that you join to from the fact table multiple times.  This is called a role playing dimension.  Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT fact.*
,COALESCE(moc.datekey, @unknownDateKey)
,COALESCE(sent.datekey, @unknownDateKey)
FROM factTable fact
LEFT OUTER JOIN date moc
ON fact.mocdate = moc.date
LEFT OUTER JOIN date sent
ON fact.sentdate = sent.date
```

You would have the `@unknownDateKey` as a variable above that is set to the key of the unknown member for the dimension.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do with the date dimension table, I am joining the table with all these dates several times with the particular dates to the dates dimension but I am getting repeats and incorrect sums than if I run my original query which does the aggregates in 2 seperate queries with different where clauses. The date dimension table has the master date column to which I am trying to join. then I will have one date column to filter on to get counts on all the subjects. I want one dataset for my ssrs report you see.

Comment: please see my comment on post above

Comment: It might help if you post the schema as it is kind of confusing why you have multiple date tables.